# bash sed does not replace several occurences of search pattern

Tags: bash, replace, sed

Given string:

```
var nav_str = "/index.html,/upgrade.html,/backup.html,/clock.html,/reset.html";
```

should be converted to:

```
var nav_str = "/home/sz/index.html,/home/sz/upgrade.html,/home/sz/backup.html,/home/sz/clock.html,/home/sz/reset.html";
```

using the below code:

```
sed -i -e "s|/\(.*\.html\)|$(pwd)&|g" $FILE
```

but only get:

```
var nav_str = "/home/sz/index.html,/upgrade.html,/backup.html,/clock.html,/reset.html";
```

Comment: `sed` is not provided by `bash`; it's provided by your operating system, and will behave identically no matter which shell invokes it (or if it's started with no shell at all; ie. by Python, Java, C, or another language via `fork()` and `execve()`). The bash tag thus doesn't belong on this question.

Comment: ...btw, I'd also tend to lean towards the `perl` answer by @DrewBeres simply because the `-i` argument to `sed` is an extension which not all versions of `sed` support (and some that do support it do so in a different and incompatible way; for instance, your code won't work on MacOS), whereas you can use `-i` on a perl one-liner with a reasonable level of assurance that it'll work the same way whatever your platform, so long as any perl interpreter built within the last several decades is installed.

Comment: ...as another aside, consider `$PWD` rather than `$(pwd)`; the latter is literally orders of magnitude slower to evaluate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sed's regular expressions match the longest strings, not the shortest.   Consequently, `/\(.*\.html\)` matches from the *first* `/` to the *last* `.html`.

Because your data is comma-separated, there is an easy work-around: replace `.*` with `[^,]*`.  Thus, try:

```
sed  -e "s|/\([^,]*\.html\)|$(pwd)&|g" file
```

Answer (score 2):

For a Perl solution implementing a lazy quantifier:

```
perl -pe "s|(/.*?\.html)|$(pwd)\1|g" file
```